# The Microsoft Crypto API (CAPI) in powerbuilder

Tags: asp.net, sybase, powerbuilder, mscapi

I'm looking for examples information on how to extract certificate information from the windows certificate store and perform operations like verifying signatures using the retrieved certificates.The particular certificate will be provided via a USB token. Any help or pointers would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Cryto sample program available on Sybase code-exchange, it may require logging into the Sybase site and you'll need to migrate it to your current version of PB.  The download location is:

http://downloads.sybase.com/codexchange/powerbuilder/923/PBCrypto.zip

Also, you can find some code samples of using Crypto API on a Windows machine here:

http://www.rgagnon.com/pbdetails/pb-0170.html